# Spiral Text using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to display the curriculum for a course along a spiral converging inwards. The curriculum has 4 modules and I want to associate a distinct color to each of those module (say different shades of blue, red, green and orange). The colors will help to demarcate when we move from one module to another. And two adjacent topics from the same module are demarcated by different shades of the same color.

I am trying to make such a plot using `d3.js`. I found [this useful example](https://bl.ocks.org/arpitnarechania/027e163073864ef2ac4ceb5c2c0bf616) and I have been trying to tinker around with it. But I have been unable to get it to look as per my needs.

Can you please give me a minimal working code that I can edit to my needs?

The input data would look like this:

```
1. Topic 1, Module 1
2. Topic 2, Module 1
3. Topic 3, Module 2
4. Topic 4, Module 3
5. Topic 5, Module 1
6. Topic 6, Module 4
7. Topic 7, Module 1
8. Topic 8, Module 2
9. Topic 9, Module 3
```

and so on.

And output is supposed to look something like this:

[image: Spiral Text (Apologies for my bad drawing skills)]

EDIT: These are some of the things I have tried:

1. I need to add a thickness to the radial line. So I tried using `d3.arc` instead of `d3.radialLine`. But that didn't work.

Comment: I notice the question has been down-voted. Can you please suggest improvements to the question?

Comment: Not my downvote - but improvement suggestion per *I have been trying to tinker around with it.* - you should add your tinkering code and say where you are stuck with it.

Comment: Perhaps you could mix this one? https://observablehq.com/d/4ae99ea3f974325a. I forked it from [this](https://observablehq.com/@gorm/arshjul). And made just a few changes.

Comment: Thanks for the [link](https://observablehq.com/@gorm/arshjul). However, is the link to the observablehq.com perhaps broken? If you can fix, I would be very interested to check it out.